# Trouble creating credentials in Azure

Tags: azure, ssl, https, credentials

I'm using the [GetSSL - Azure Automation](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/GetSSL-LetsEncrypt/1.4.3/DisplayScript) PowerShell script to set up a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate in Azure. As part of this, I've had to set up an Azure AD User for the script to use.

However, when running the script, it errors when running the `Get-AutomationPSCredential` cmdlet:

> Credentials asset not found. To create this Credentials asset, navigate to the Assets blade and create a Credentials asset named: myuser@mydomain.com.

But, when I attempt to create a credential in the Azure Portal I see this error:

[image: This marketplace item is not available]

So, I'm a bit stuck.

Any advice about creating credentials in Azure (or indeed setting up a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate!) is welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not following correct steps to create Automation credentials.

To create new credential go your created automation account in Azure Portal. In the left option pane of Automation Account, scroll down to Shared Resources section and click on Credentials option. Select Add a credential option on top to create new credential.

[image]

Also you have an option to use below Windows Powershell to create Automation credential -

```
$user = "MyDomain\MyUser"
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString "PassWord!" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $user, $pw
New-AzureAutomationCredential -AutomationAccountName "MyAutomationAccount" -Name "MyCredential" -Value $cred
```